# Javascript syntax error unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error, token

```
function queue_instructions(){
        var input_message = "Commands
    w?  Shows whos on the waitlist
    w+  Adds yourself to the waitlist
    w-  Removes yourself from the waitlist
    w++  Moves yourself down one spot on the waitlist
    -mods  Shows a list of available moderators
    -plays  Shows how many songs each DJ has played
    -promote  Requests a vote from everyone for you to be moved to 1st on the list
    -pull [#]  Requests a vote from everyone to pull that DJ off the booth  Number of DJ is     what number spot he is on the booth  Numbers read from left to right
    -remove [#]  Removes that number DJ from the waitlist  Must be a moderator
    -votekick [username]  Requests a vote from everyone to kick the user
     Type -help [command] for more info on a command (ie. -help w?)";
        deliver_chat(input_message);
```

I get a syntax error unexpected toke illegal on my Javascript console on Google chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to close those quotes on each line, and concatenate with `+` to the next line:

```
var input_message = "Commands " + 
    "w?  Shows whos on the waitlist " + 
    "w+  Adds yourself to the waitlist " +
```

and so on

Did you want line breaks to be inserted with each line?  If so, you can use `\n`:

```
var input_message = "Commands\n" + 
    "w?  Shows whos on the waitlist\n" + 
    "w+  Adds yourself to the waitlist\n" +
```

Answer (score 1):

When you split a string over multiple lines, you need to concatenate it with `+` like this

```
var input_message = "Commands"+
"w?  Shows whos on the waitlist"+
"w+  Adds yourself to the waitlist"+
"w-  Removes yourself from the waitlist"+
"w++  Moves yourself down one spot on the waitlist"+
"-mods  Shows a list of available moderators"+
"-plays  Shows how many songs each DJ has played"+;
```

---

And also in your code, I don't find the closing curly brace `}` of that function.

```
function queue_instructions()
{
     //Stuff here.
}
```

you need to include it.

Comment: Well you're the one who took the time to edit this question, so a +1 is the least I can do :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. You'll need to either put the whole string in one line OR close the quotes in each line a do a + to concat the next line with it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you do like this:

```
var input_message = [
    "Commands",
    "w?  Shows whos on the waitlist",
    "w+  Adds yourself to the waitlist",
    "w-  Removes yourself from the waitlist",
    "w++  Moves yourself down one spot on the waitlist",
    "-mods  Shows a list of available moderators",
    "-plays  Shows how many songs each DJ has played",
    "-promote  Requests a vote from everyone for you to be moved to 1st on the list",
    "-pull [#]  Requests a vote from everyone to pull that DJ off the booth  Number of DJ is what number spot he is on the booth  Numbers read from left to right",
    "-remove [#]  Removes that number DJ from the waitlist  Must be a moderator",
    "-votekick [username]  Requests a vote from everyone to kick the user",
    "Type -help [command] for more info on a command (ie. -help w?)"
].join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice no-one has suggested escaping the line-ending:

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line \
    This is the second line \
    This is more...";
```

Note that the line endings are included in this string…

http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings