# jQuery : getting PHP variables by AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is fairly simple but somehow I was able to not get it to work, even by searching on google. I have a php variable that I would like to use in javascript. I tried to do something like

```
var fullLink = <?php echo $_SESSION['fullLink']; ?>;
```

but nope I got a "Uncaught syntaxerror : Unexpected Token" error so I guessed it was because of the php tags or somewhere near there. Then I tried in AJAX, but then I keep getting the full html. I tried creating another file just to test and see what was the problem but I was able to get the variable which says that it's my first file that has a problem, but dunno what.
I'm pretty sure it's a frequent error but wasn't successful on getting an answer on google.

Edit 1 : Alright to be more straightforward, I'm trying to build dynamically a link on a blog I'm coding that will allow the user to share the post on facebook. Don't wanna use the "like" plugin from Facebook but the share (sharer.php) and then do a window.open() with the link. The problem is building the link with the title, mini-description and link of the blog post.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

you missed `"` operator there

```
var fullLink = "<?php echo $_SESSION['fullLink']; ?>";
  //-----------^------------------------------------^ here
```

this will print the fulllink as string and var fullLink will get that value as string...

Comment: I don'T see what you mean there. I tried to write the php code within the " " and without it, still same result.

Comment: are you sure your are getting the `$_SESSION` value.. if yes then this should work no doubt... i think , the problem is in session variable here...

Comment: As @bipen said - if the " " aren't working then you have a problem with the actual session variable

Comment: I added the quotes and it's saying Unexpected token illegal on that line

Comment: its not that code that is giving you error .. its the unwanted spaces or the new lines inside the quote..have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612344/javascript-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal .. this might solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Providing this is within a PHP file you'll just need to add the `"` operator.

```
var fullLink = "<?php echo $_SESSION['fullLink']; ?>";
```

That will work providing that `$_SESSION['fullLink']` exists.

**UPDATE**

There must be some other issue in your code, I have just created a test script using the `fullLink` from your source example, and the `window.open()` code you provided. It worked fine with just these parts:

```
<script>
    var fullLink = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=localhost:8080/BetaFolioBlogOOP??/Blog/post/5-2e-post&p[title]=2e post&p[summary]= Voici mon deuxi&egrave;me post question de voir si le tout marche bien ! ";
    window.open(fullLink, "Facebook_share", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=500");      
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it is, I just didn't write the whole code since there's at least 150 lines in total.

Comment: That's fine then, you just need to add the quotes. :)

Comment: Now it's saying Unexpected token illegal. So my question may be dumb but what are the illegal token possible ? FYI I edited the post to give more explanation.

Comment: Just tried to copy the same exact string I'm supposed to receive in another file that I use only to test it and everything goes smoothly. So there must be something else that interfere, no ?

Comment: If you view source i.e. all the HTML/JavaScript in the browser. What do you see for the line in question?

Comment: I get this : `var fullLink = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=localhost:8080/BetaFolioBlogOOP/Blog/post/5-2e-post&p[title]=2e post&p[summary]=
 Voici mon deuxi&egrave;me post question de voir si le tout marche bien !
";`

Comment: Interesting... the link works if I paste it directly into the browser.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. I tried using it in another file (where there's only the html tags) with the SAME link and I get this error... depending on what I do, I either get the full html of the sending page, or those two js errors Oo

Comment: Can you provide the JS you use to make the request using this variable?

Comment: `$.get("getFBLink.php", {},function(data){
   console.log(data);
   },"json");` Yeah doesn't look really good in comment -.-

Comment: Sorry, I meant the bit where you use the `fullLink` with `window.open()`.

Comment: Only the line would be this : `window.open(fullLink, "Facebook_share", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=500");`

Comment: Yep me too I got that -.- what kind of issue would interfere with that ?

Comment: Could be anything, you could have missed a semi-colon `;` or curly bracket `}` somewhere. You'll have to check.

Comment: From what I was able to see, there is a problem in the string (in "http://www.facebook.com ....."), there seems to be a character he doesn't like Oo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var fullLink = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fullLink']); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP : calling javascript function

```
func($_SESSION['fullLink']);
```

or better:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fullLink']))
{ func($_SESSION['fullLink']); }
```

Javascript:

```
function func(link){

var fulllink = link;
...}
```